# Trying to block a Indy connection (Incoming)

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I intent to block certain clients from connecting to my server. I have the following code segments:

```
procedure TMain.WebServiceConnect(AContext:TIdContext);

Var
  IP:String;

begin
  try
    IP:=AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
    if Allowlist.IndexOf(IP)=-1 then Begin;
      if Blocklist.IndexOf(IP)>-1 then Begin;
        LogWrite('Blocking IP "'+IP+'"!',Detailed);
        LogRequest(IP,'*BLOCKED*');
        AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
      End;
    End;
  except
    ON E:Exception do
      LogWrite('"'+E.Message+'" while connection-check on blocklist',Detailed);
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.WebServiceReceive(AContext:TIdContext; ARequestInfo:TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo:TIdHTTPResponseInfo);

begin
  try
    try
      LogWrite('Handling connection from '+ARequestInfo.RemoteIP,Debug);
      AResponseInfo.ResponseNo:=401;
      ProcessWebRequest(AContext,ARequestInfo,AResponseInfo);
      LogWrite('Closing connection to '+ARequestInfo.RemoteIP,Debug);
    except
      ON E:Exception do
        LogWrite('"'+E.Message+'" while handling request!',verbose,FALSE);
    End;
  finally
  End;
End;
```

But I see both events trigger from blocked IPs! I *do* see the "blocked" logline, but it seems the `AContext.Connection.Disconnect` doesnt act as expected.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see no possible way that the server's `OnCommand...` events can be fired for a given client connection if the `OnConnect` event has closed that connection. The server would fail to read the client's request data to populate the `TIdRequestInfo` object before firing the `OnCommand...` events.

So, either you are not actually calling `Disconnect()` like you are expecting, or you are misdiagnosing the issue.

For instance, in your log messages, try including the `AContext.Binding.PeerPort`, or even the `AContext.Binding.Handle`, in addition to the `PeerIP` to make sure the log messages actually belong to the same client connection. `PeerIP` alone is not adequate to uniquely identify individual connections.

That being said, in the unlikely situation that `Disconnect()` is actually not closing the connection, you can force a disconnect by raising an exception, such as via `SysUtils.Abort()`, so that the server will terminate the calling thread and close the socket.

Also, speaking of exceptions, you should re-raise any exception that you catch with `except` (or, at least, any Indy exception derived from `EIdException`), let the server handle it.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure TMain.WebServiceConnect(AContext:TIdContext);
var
  IP: String;
  Port: TIdPort;
begin
  try
    IP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
    Port := AContext.Binding.PeerPort;
    if Allowlist.IndexOf(IP) = -1 then begin
      if Blocklist.IndexOf(IP) > -1 then begin
        LogWrite('Blocking IP "' + IP + ':' + IntToStr(Port) + '"!', Detailed);
        LogRequest(IP, '*BLOCKED*');
        AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
        SysUtils.Abort;
      end;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      if not (E is EAbort) then
        LogWrite('"' + E.Message + '" while connection-check on blocklist', Detailed);
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.WebServiceReceive(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  IP: String;
  Port: TIdPort;
begin
  try
    IP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
    Port := AContext.Binding.PeerPort;
    LogWrite('Handling connection from ' + IP + ':' + IntToStr(Port), Debug);
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 401;
    ProcessWebRequest(AContext, ARequestInfo, AResponseInfo);
    LogWrite('Closing connection to ' + IP + ':' + IntToStr(Port), Debug);
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      LogWrite('"' + E.Message + '" while handling request!', verbose, FALSE);
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```